# How to dynamically check if an element has mulitple class using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I know a DOM element has more than one class?

For instance, knowing that the element may have one or both of `test` and `b` classes, I would check if it both classes are present in the following manner:

```
if(jQuery(a).hasClass('test') && jQuery(a).hasClass('b'){  
    //Do  something`
}
```

But I need to cover the case whereby I don't know what classes may be present.

Comment: `if ($(a).is('.test.b'))`

Comment: why do you want to do that... if create the case using element `a` then the a will always return true for that

Comment: What you are doing is ok, what do you mean by generating it dynamically, can you give a better example?

Comment: By "dynamically", do you mean the class names are not known?

Comment: @jayson Buquia Yes Class names are not known they can be anything and will be generated by the user

Comment: @NickN. I am trying to change colors show different products when a user clicks on a category. For instance if a user selects two category say , a and b , then the products who have both category should be hihglighted and the rest should not and like wise if a user selects 3 category then the products with all 3 categories should be highlight, if a prodcut has only have one of those 3 categories then that product should not be highlighted

Comment: You can check my answer below....

Comment: This looks like you want a collection of those selected classes and then just loop through, instead of dynamically creating the if statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    jQuery('selector').click(function () { // The event trigger
 var finalClass = []; // array to store all the classes which has been triggered by the event
        var i=0;
        jQuery('.collaps-list li').each(function () {
            finalClass[i] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            i++;
        });  
jQuery(selector).each(function () {
            var $flag =0;
            for(i=0;i<finalClass.length;i++){
                if (jQuery(this).find('a').hasClass(finalClass[i])) {
                    $flag=1;
                }
                else{
                    $flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($flag==1){
                jQuery(this).find('img').removeClass('grayscale');
            }
});
```

This worked for me

Comment: how exactly does this answer your question?

Comment: Well first i had to add the selected elements in an array(). Then using .each() i checked for each value of array in my DOM element. As long as there is a value of the array in my element i keep the loop running. However if there isn't any value of the array in the element then i change the value of flag to 0 and break the loop.Now i check my value of flag. If the value of flag =1 then execute else don't. If you are still confused do let me know i will try clarify even more. But do tell which part confuses the most

Comment: I am not confused. If you know what you are doing and you are confident about it, then that's great. You probably should select your own answer as the answer to this question. Cheers!

Comment: It was a hit and trial method

Comment: Other answer may be exact, sure to work and written with a clear logic. You may try them, and if one solves your problem completely, select that one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which takes an element and a particular class to search for.
What it does is iterates through all the classes that the element passed is a part of
and if it finds a match for the search value, you can define behaviour in the if statement.

You can call it as follows `doSomething('#element', 'error'));`

```
function doSomething(elementid, classname)
{
    var classes = $(elementid).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each( classes, function(index, current){        
        if (current == classname) {
            //do something here
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: please describe your function so other user will get idea of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the class names aren't known, you can try something like this:

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0uk3Le/1/)***

```
<div class="test b" id="foo"></div>

===========================================
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
if (elem.className.match(/ /)) {
    alert('class names: '+elem.className)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one way to do that with jQuery, and here goes:

```
var numberOfClasses = jQuery(element).attr("class").trim().split(/\s+/).length;

if(numberOfClasses > 1){
    // do what Ayush wants
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery : 
If $(element).attr("class").indexOf(' ') is not -1 then there are more than one class.

```
function hasMultipleClasses(elem) {
   if(elem.attr("class").indexOf(' ')>-1) 
    return true;
   else return false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3t5719r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Please check this.

```
// This code will returns all the based on the selector and split them based on empty seperator
var arr = jQuery(a).attr('class').split(' ');

//Removes all empty strings
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function( a ) {

    return a !== '';

});

// This condition will be satisfied on if the selector contains multiple classes
if(arr.length > 1){

  //Code to execute

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery to do that is a little bit powerfull don't you think?

You can do it using native Javascript, with something like that:

```
element.className.trim().split(/ /).length > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want a collection of those selected classes and then just loop through, instead of dynamically creating the if statement.

```
var selectedClasses = [ "test", "b" ];

var hasAllClasses = CheckIfAllClassesAvailable(a, selectedClasses);


function CheckIfAllClassesAvailable(a, selectedClasses) {

    //loop through all the selected classes
    for(String s : selectedClasses)
    {
        //check if the class is not available
        if(!jQuery(a).hasClass(s))
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if this code works syntactly (please see this as pseudocode), but I think this is the way to go, you then just have to create the array with the selected categories dynamically, which you can do with a simple call to a webservice, think about it.

You can rewrite this to a shorter variant if you use some nice jQuery one liners, but I think this is more clear for now.